# how to get total specs count and pass and fail specs count in jasmine 2 and protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor, jasmine-node, jasmine2.0

I want to generate the emailable report after my test suite gets completed using Jasmine and protractor.

How can I get the following information after my test suite is completed.

1.Total no of spec count
2.Total pass spec count
3.Total Failed test spec count
4. Total Pending specs counts

I could not find any proper solution so far. Please help me out solve this issue.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter

Answer (score 0):

Using the spec-reporter writes down on your console the results of your testing, but if you really need something to email, you could also use jasmine2-html-reporter, which generates an html page with the results.
With that file, you can program a function to send via email a file or something that you need

[CONSOLE: Jasmine spec reporter](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/tree/9ec77f2fa10ead4eb00b901a4fbb74e6a6ab7e2e)

[HTML: Jasmine html reporter](https://github.com/Kenzitron/protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter)